# Troubleshoot Broken reference:

Tags: magento2, theme, reference

All the templates in my custom child theme suddenly started showing a white screen. The error logs showing the following:

```
[2020-08-10 17:29:28] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "before.body.end" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
```

I've removed any reference to before.body.end and cleared caches but the white screen and this error still persist.